# how to solve the GWTEXT calendar problem?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using the project with GwtExt and Gwt-windows-1.5.2,
When I deploy my project to a local server: http: localhost / project;
the Date component displays correctly ‘the correct values from the database’
But when I deploy the project on a remote server and I access it via an address for example: http: 172.12.15.1/projet; all the pages of my project: show me the date component with a value less than one day:
For example the value of the database is:
06/14/2021 in the database => it shows me: 06/13/2021

I don't know how I can distinguish this problem; because when I debug it locally I can't find where the error persists,
How to do it please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would check for time zone differences, because, for example `2021-06-16 00:00:00`  at time zone `+01` equals `2021-06-15 23:00:00` UTC.

Comment: no it's not a question of time zone; any other idea please?